# Replace string and int values in HIVE table

Tags: hadoop, replace, hive, translate

I want to replace all the values of a specific column in hive table to random values using regex_replace.

How can I do that.

Its similar like we do in shell scripting :-

```
tr '[a-j]' '[j-s]'
```

or

```
tr '[1-4]' '[5-8]'
```

or is there any other way to replace values in hive.

I can replace 1 value using

```
select cust_id, regexp_replace(cust_id, '23456', '74563') as cust_id from cust_table;
```

but I want to replace all the values of 100 rows with random numbers.

Comment: There may be a small chance of collisions with random numbers, I am assuming you don't want the same number repeated.

Comment: No I don't want to repeat same number. Number should be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regexp for this, you can simply use a combination of `rand` and `round` to generate a random number for each row. For example, if you want to generate random numbers between 0 and 10000 :

```
select round(rand() * 10000) as cust_id from cust_table
```

`rand` returns a random double from 0 to 1 and `round` returns the rounded value as a bigint